# Text on image in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to write the value of count rather than the string "count" on image
How can I do it?

```
htxtins = vision.TextInserter('count');

htxtins.Color = [255, 255, 255]; 
htxtins.FontSize = 24;
htxtins.Location = [5 50]; 
J = step(htxtins,frame);
```

Comment: This code as it is does not make any sense. Please post relevant code or a minimal example and tell us about what toolbox you're actually talking about.

Comment: The code looks ok to me? Anyway, @AnderBiguri beat us to the answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the value of count is stored in a variable named `count` then

```
vision.TextInserter(num2str(count));
```

will do.

In case you want to create a more complex string you could use `strcat`, e.g.

```
strcat('Count =',num2str(count))
```